# How to convert Pandas dataframe to dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
Name age job
John 25 Scientist
```

I want to create a dict like this:

```
'John': [25, 'Scientist']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> {v[0]: v[1:] for v in df.values.tolist()}
{'John': [25, 'Scientist']}
```

or

```
>>> df.set_index("Name").T.to_dict(orient="list")
{'John': [25, 'Scientist']}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `set_index("Name")`
2. `to_dict(orient="index")` gets close to your requirement
3. a **dict** comprehension to change columns from a **dict** to a **list**

```
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Name age job
John 25 Scientist"""),sep="\s+")

{k:list(v.values()) for k,v in df.set_index("Name").to_dict(orient="index").items()}
```

#### output

{'John': [25, 'Scientist']}